# Groupon Daily Emails

Tags: email, groupon

Can you change the time of day groupon daily emails are sent to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the emails are sent by Groupon itself at their own scheduled time.  They're designed to go out just before the deals are available, queued by their own servers.

Due to their morning release schedules, they don't permit you to customize the time of day that you receive the email from them, as they send them out in bulk to all of their subscribers - not individually to users.

The only "timing delay" would be the length of time it takes their application to generate all of the emails and queue them for delivery, and the time it takes to get to your email server!

Answer (score 0):

Why not subscribe to your local Groupon RSS feed, and then find an RSS to E-Mail service (such as [feedmyinbox.com](http://feedmyinbox.com)) to send you updates to the RSS feed at a time you specify.